# Custom Post Pagination with Parameters - 404

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

my pagination for my custom post search is working great, however I find that certain works cause the pagination to 404. For example,

/page/2/?s=York&post_type=property&distance=3 works fine

/page/2/?s=Huntington&post_type=property&distance=3 doesn't work

Can anyone think of why certain terms could possible break pagination?

Answer (score 0):

I seems that, you trying to access the page which does not exist.

Lets take an example you have total 15 post in DB and your page size is 10 post per page.

Here you can seen page 1(contains 10 posts) & 2(contains 5 posts) but if you will enter `page/3/` this url it will throw 404 error.

Hope you got your answer.

Comment: <?php echo $location_query->found_posts;?> shows me that there should be 44 results though. And i'm paginating by 20.

Comment: Also, increasing the posts_per_page shows all 44 - so its def a pagination issue for certain search terms

Comment: I was doing this in Spring boot. Not sure  for php.